# URI Library for Python

Tags: python, uri

I am planning to build my own URI module/class in python to get a grasp on URIs and python. Could you please suggest me links for blogs/sites/etc for a complete reference on URIs and where to begin with, the RFCs not to be missed and any other source of help. This is not a part of my homework assignment.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `URI`? uniform resource identifier? That could mean many things and what are you trying to accomplish?? What do you mean by building your own module?

Comment: There are python modules for like urllib, urllib2 and urlparse. I am trying to implement something on the similar lines with more ease of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You know [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) exists right?

It will probably be better than what you are intending to write.

Comment: I know about it. I am trying to implement this as a way to brush up my python skills and learn more about uris

Comment: But what do you want to learn about URLs? `urllib` kind are not about urls. They are about http requests and http responses. This is what `requests` library does - it abstracts the heaviness of `urlib` from regular user. So that's another interesting library to look at. If you want to learn more about http, you probably will be looking at `socket` at the lowest level. But once again, exactly whar do you want to know more about `URL` that can help boost your Python skill?