# Is there a standard generic URI handler in Python?

Tags: java, python, oop, sdk

Typically, an [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Examples) (Universal Resource Identifier) can be:

- a local or remote file
- a web URL
- a binary stream

What is the standard way to manage this in Python?

Something like:

```
uri = URI("whatever_URI)
```

In the Java world for example you've got the class [`java.net.URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URI Library for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747320/uri-library-for-python)

Comment: does urllib handle any URI? "urllib is a package that collects several modules for working with **URL**s:"

Comment: URIs are far more general than that. What would handlers for an `http` URI and a `mailto` URI have in common?

Comment: that they both comply with the naming scheme, for example and can have a relatable resource (file/email address exists/not exists). Maybe ```urllib2``` could be what I am looking for, therefore - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'uri' library of PyPI(Python Package Index:- it is like a repository of Python Packages).

• Install it using:

```
pip install uri
```

For MAC use:

```
pip3 install uri
```

• Use it like below

```
from uri import URI
home = URI("https://github.com/marrow/")
print(home)
```

For more information, You can visit this:
https://pypi.org/project/uri/